# Responsive adsense with maxwidth not working

Tags: css, ads, adsense

I'm using this line of code to insert ads in a website:

```
<div style="max-width:816px; width:100%;">
<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block;max-width:816px; width:100%; clear:both" data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxx" data-ad-slot="xxxxxx" data-ad-format="auto" data-full-width-responsive="true">
</ins></div>
```

Most of the time it works perfect, but sometimes the ads load with a different max-width: 1110px;

There are a few other ads that comes with 1110px width, which I think is the maximum size of the page, but I thought that limiting the  tag or the div container would solve it, but it didn't.

What can be the reason? Even if I remove the "width: 100%" it still breaks the limit and change the max-width on it's on.

EDIT:

Source example:
[image: Source]
And inspect example:
[image]

Comment: Do you or the site you're working on have any media queries of any kind? Because the portion of code you provided does exactly what it should on its own but it's kind of hard to tell where the 1100px width could be coming from otherwise. Do you have a screenshot of this happening or can you put together a [mre] for it? https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9183363?hl=en

Comment: I edited and inserted two screenshots, one from the source from a loaded page, and the inspect code, showing the different ad size.
I know there is some @media, but I'm not sure if that could be messing with that. It's not everytime that the width change sizes, sometimes it stays in the defined limit.

Comment: Is the loaded page on your hosted live site? I'd almost wonder if your platform or provider isn't injecting their own rules like the one I work with. I run into this stuff with ads, CSS styling, and so on at my job. I end up adding the !important flag which isn't great practice but it's the only workaround they've ever offered me.

Comment: Yeah, it is. It's a news site. I will try to add the !important flag in the style to see if it works.

Comment: @AStombaugh even with style="display:block;max-width:816px !important; width:100%;clear:both" it still changed the max-width... guess that won't work with me.